# Rust, returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Tags: rust

I checked forum for this question, I found some answers, but any of this situation was different and don't work for me.

I have problem with this error:

```
let test = PasswordHash::new(&hashed_password).clone().unwrap();
   |                                      ---------------- `hashed_password` is borrowed here
53 |         // Ok(PasswordHash::new(&hashed_password).unwrap())
54 |         Ok(test)
   |         ^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I exactly know what this error means. I know where the problem is, and I even know what provide it. But have no idea how can I fix it.

My idea it don't repeat part of code which is responsible for generating PasswordHash. I decided create separate function to do this.

My code below:

```
use argon2::{
    password_hash::{
        rand_core::OsRng,
        PasswordHash, PasswordHasher, PasswordVerifier, SaltString, Error
    },
    Argon2,
};

struct AlgorithmData {
    version: u32,
    params: String,
    algorithm_type: String,
}
impl AlgorithmData {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let example_string = "example_string";
        let password_hash = Hasher::get_passwordhash_object(&example_string).unwrap();

        AlgorithmData { version: password_hash.version.unwrap(),
                        params: password_hash.params.to_string(),
                        algorithm_type: password_hash.algorithm.to_string() }
    }
}
pub struct Hasher {}

impl Hasher {    
    pub fn hash_string(string_to_hash: &str) -> Result<String, Error> {
        let parsed_hash_password = Hasher::get_passwordhash_object(string_to_hash)?;

        let result = format!("{}${}",
                                     parsed_hash_password.salt.unwrap().to_string(),
                                     parsed_hash_password.hash.unwrap().to_string());
        
        Ok(result)
    }

    fn get_passwordhash_object(string_to_hash: &str) -> Result<PasswordHash, Error> {
        let bytes_to_hash = string_to_hash.as_bytes();
        
        let salt = SaltString::generate(&mut OsRng);
        let argon2 = Argon2::default();

        let hashed_password = argon2.hash_password(&bytes_to_hash,
                                                           &salt)?.to_string();
        
        let test = PasswordHash::new(&hashed_password).clone().unwrap();
        // Ok(PasswordHash::new(&hashed_password).unwrap()) --> here too is problem
        Ok(test) // here is the same problem
    }

    pub fn compare_string_to_hash(string_to_compare: &String,
                                  hash_to_compare: &String) -> Result<bool, Error> {
        let bytes_to_compare = string_to_compare.as_bytes();
        let bytes_from_hash = PasswordHash::new(&hash_to_compare).unwrap();

        Ok(Argon2::default().verify_password(&bytes_to_compare,
                                             &bytes_from_hash).is_ok())
    }    
}
```

Like you see main problem is variable: hashed_password and it reference in new object PasswordHash.

I was tried use copy function to clone hashed_password variable or object PasswordHash.
Second thing was trying to use lifetime parameter like <'a>.
Third idea was using Box::new to try access to memory directly.

I need help to resolve this problem. I have already read documentation. But still have no more ideas to resolve this.

Error number: E0515 explaining reason quite well.

Comment: The only answer I can give is "don't extract this into a function". Sorry.

Comment: Nit: You should probably take `&str` instead of `&String` it's less indirection, more general and smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely have a lifetime issue here. In your case, the `PasswordHash` lifetime depends on the `SaltString`. So, if you want to send a reference of `PasswordHash` out to the caller, it's better to take `SaltString` as an argument to the function `get_passwordhash_object`.

Here is the minimal example derived from your code:

```
use argon2::{
    password_hash::{rand_core::OsRng, Error, PasswordHash, PasswordHasher, SaltString},
    Argon2,
};
pub struct Hasher {}

impl Hasher {
    fn get_passwordhash_object<'a>(
        bytes_to_hash: &'a [u8],
        salt: &'a SaltString,
    ) -> Result<PasswordHash<'a>, Error> {
        let argon2 = Argon2::default();

        let hashed_password = argon2.hash_password(&bytes_to_hash, salt).unwrap();
        Ok(hashed_password)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let salt = SaltString::generate(&mut OsRng);
    let hash = Hasher::get_passwordhash_object("something".as_bytes(), &salt);
    println!("{:?}", hash);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help! I think this will be best solution. 
Truly appreciate your spended time on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [`PasswordHash::new`](https://docs.rs/argon2/latest/argon2/struct.PasswordHash.html#method.new) you will see that it returns a struct with the same lifetime of the parameter. In your case the the `test` variable lifetime depends on the lifetime of `hashed_password`, that itself depends on the lifetime of `salt`, that owns its data.

In the `get_passwordhash_object`, you can't return `PasswordHash` type and discard the salt, you need to return both, or transform the data in something else that owns its data.

One solution is to serialize the `PasswordHash` into `PasswordHashString`, because this type owns his data

```rust
pub fn hash_string(string_to_hash: &str) -> Result<String, Error> {
    let parsed_hash_password =
        Hasher::get_passwordhash_object(string_to_hash)?;

    let result = format!(
        "{}${}",
        parsed_hash_password.salt().unwrap().to_string(),
        parsed_hash_password.hash().unwrap().to_string()
    );

    Ok(result)
}

fn get_passwordhash_object(
    string_to_hash: &str,
) -> Result<PasswordHashString, Error> {
    let bytes_to_hash = string_to_hash.as_bytes();

    let salt = SaltString::generate(&mut OsRng);
    let argon2 = Argon2::default();

    let hashed_password =
        argon2.hash_password(&bytes_to_hash, &salt)?.to_string();

    let test = PasswordHash::new(&hashed_password).clone().unwrap();
    Ok(test.serialize())
}

pub fn compare_string_to_hash(
    string_to_compare: &String,
    hash_to_compare: &String,
) -> Result<bool, Error> {
    let bytes_to_compare = string_to_compare.as_bytes();
    let bytes_from_hash = PasswordHash::new(&hash_to_compare).unwrap();

    Ok(Argon2::default()
        .verify_password(&bytes_to_compare, &bytes_from_hash)
        .is_ok())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I checked your proposition and it working fine. But i choose Nick's answer.

Thanks for your time! :)